# Prepositions and Corners

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, american-english, vocabulary

Does one use "on" or "at" in the following:

> Kate met him at the corner
>
> Kate met him on the corner.

Or are they the same?

Comment: [Standing on the Corner Watching All the Girls Go By](http://www.metrolyrics.com/standing-on-the-corner-lyrics-dean-martin.html) /// 
Standing on the corner //
 Watching all the girls go by // 
Standing on the corner // 
Giving all the girls the eye ///  This is idiomatic American English, but "[at the corner](http://bulletin.arcadia.edu/2011/11/from-inspiration-to-fruition-schrift-12-writes-and-directs-original-musical/)" is too.

Answer (score 2):

I personally stand "on" the corner of 12th St and Vine.  I would more commonly use "on". The "store on the corner" sounds better to me than the "store at the corner", but I've heard both.

I use "at" more with "intersection", which can be a corner.  If I were imparting the location of an accident, for example, I might say one car hit the other right at the intersection of Wabash and Central.

I think either is probably correct.  I wouldn't immediately peg a person using one or the other for a native or nonnative speaker or to be from this or that region.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the street corner, then you can use ***on*** or ***at***; they pretty much mean the same thing.

If you mean the corner of a room, then you can use ***in*** or ***at***, depending on the context:

> That sectional sofa meets **in** the corner of the room.
>
> That sectional sofa meets **at** the corner of the room.

The prepositions *at*, *in*, and *on* are versitile little buggers with many overlapping nuances in certain contexts.

> This antique is chipped *in/on/at* the corner.
> The painter signs her name *in/at* the corner.

In those two cases, I'd most likely use the preposition I've listed first, but I wouldn't label the others I've listed as "incorrect."